# Studio voices are GA but don't support `mark` tags

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I am getting the following error with the Google Text-to-Speech API:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: `<mark>` tags are not currently supported by Studio voices.
```

Studio voices are GA since 26th Feb 2024 per release notes. So I don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but it appears that <mark> is not yet implemented for Studio voices. I would suggest filing this as Feature Request for a possibility to get implemented and gain traction [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).